# Unchecking CheckBoxes @ ListView android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

how can i uncheck all the CheckBoxes of a ListView?
I'm extending a ArrayAdapter and i've already tried something like:

```
private void listCheckBoxesState(boolean select) {
    final ListView list = getListView();
    for(int i=0;i<getListAdapter().getCount();i++) {
        list.setItemChecked(i, select);
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work! :(

Comment: Where is the "checked" state coming from? Have you tried calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` after you update the boolean array?

Comment: the checked state comes from: AppInfo item = getItem(position);
holder.checkBox.setChecked(item.getActive());
Yes i did and it worked when i needed to check all the cb's!

Answer (score 0):

Update all of your `item`s and then call `notifyDatasetChanged`. You can do this in a method inside of your Adapter so it's more transparent for your activity.

Comment: Tried it man. :( Nothing yet! I appreciate your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried? unchecks it for me on all boxes

```
for(int i=0;i<getListAdapter().getCount();i++) {
    list.setItemChecked(i, false);
}
```